# Shorthand for extending native DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

As [explained in mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements), custom elements may be based on a native element. For Example, `<button is="my-button">`. What I'm looking for is kind of the opposite syntax. I'd like a shorthand for creating an element whose tag is custom and is based on a native element, such as `<purchase-button is="button">`. I'm not looking at add functionality to this custom element over what `HTMLButtonElement` provides. Just the name.

Yet, this doesn't work:

```
let purchaseButton = document.createElement('purchase-button', { is: 'button' })
document.body.appendChild(purchaseButton)
```

The resulting element does not extend `HTMLButtonElemenet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, and it doesn't exist in the Custom Element specification.

About this requirement, see [issue 603](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/603) in the specification forum.

Some are discussing similar needs in other issues (for example [#509](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/509), good luck for the reading...).

As a workaround, define a `<purchase-button>` custom element into which you insert a `<button>`. Then you can use a Shadow DOM with the `<slot>` element to reflect the original content of the `<purchase-button>`.

```js
customElements.define( 'purchase-button', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = '<button><slot></slot></button>'
    }
} )

PB.onclick = ev => 
  console.info( '[%s] clicked', ev.target.textContent )
```

```html
<purchase-button id=PB>Pay</purchase-button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here’s one ugly way:

```js
class PButton extends HTMLElement {}
customElements.define("purchase-button", PButton)
function PurchaseButton () {
    var pb = document.createElement('purchase-button')
    pb.__proto__ = PurchaseButton.prototype
    return pb
}
PurchaseButton.prototype.__proto__ = HTMLButtonElement.prototype
var purchaseButton = PurchaseButton()
purchaseButton.textContent = "Purchase"
purchaseButton.style = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("button")).cssText
document.body.appendChild(purchaseButton)
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" ⬅ custom <purchase-button>"))
```

```html
<button>Purchase</button> ⬅ native &lt;button&gt;<p>
```